# add_action shortcut?

Tags: php, functions, filters, actions

I think in PHP 5.4 or above (don't remember the exact version), instead of writing:

```
function some_function() {

}
add_action( 'init', 'some_function' );
```

One can pass an anonymous function:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

} );
```

Is there a better shortcut? Such as for example removing the characters `function()` if possible?

Comment: As far I know there isn't a better shortcut.

Comment: Your second example makes it nearly impossible to remove that action. Don't take shortcuts.

Comment: Yes I do understand that this way of doing it makes it impossible to remove it by another coder or by a plugin. But just for cases I think won't be touched any further by anyone, it will be useful. 

I should have mentioned it in my original comment but I have seen someone use __return_true. Hence my question.

Comment: That's the same as your first example, `__return_true` is a helper function in core. There's also `false`, `zero`, `null`, `empty_string` and `empty_array`.

Answer (score 1):

From the WordPress development reference, the [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function requires two parameters with an optional two.

The first parameter, `$tag` is a string that is the name of the action to which the `$function_to_add` is hooked.

The second parameter, `$function_to_add` is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that the WordPress developer reference states is "the name of the function you wish to be called." In actuality, it can be any callable: string corresponding to a function, an array corresponding to a static method, an array corresponding to an object method, or a closure.

The third ( optional ) parameter, `$priority`, is used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

The fourth ( optional ) parameter, `$accepted_args` is the number of arguments the function accepts.

> Is there a better shortcut? Such as for example removing the characters function() if possible?

So no. There is no shortcut at all. Passing a closure may require a few less characters, but is not a shortcut. And as explained in the comments, using a closure (anonymous function) as the callback is not recommended because it does not allow for an easy way to remove the action.